# How to handle a PDF attachment in a HTTP response body on the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, http-headers, invoice

I'm creating an invoice generator for an e-commerce website. I use [Invoice Generator API](https://invoice-generator.com/developers) to generate the invoice. This API sends the generated PDF in the response body as an application.pdf attachment.

In my rails application, on the invoice_controller#new form, I ask the user to input the invoice period, and on the invoice_controller#create action, I pass invoice data to this invoice-generator API, and the response body has the invoice.

It can be written into a pdf file locally as follows.

```
File.open('invoice.pdf', 'wb') do |f|
   f.write(response.body)
end
```

But this is not useful in production as long as I want to return this invoice pdf to the client when they submit the invoice_controller#new form. What I tried to do is use the `send_data` method on the invoice_controller#create action:

```
def create
    @invoice = generate_invoice #we have the pdf file in the response body
    send_data(@invoice, { filename: 'invoice.pdf', type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline" })
end
```

As a result, I see on the rails server log:
[image]

And I can see from the Chrome dev tools network tab that the response has the PDF file. But I don't know how to serve it to the user. Is it possible to do it this way, or do I have first to save it on the cloud?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"we have the pdf file in the response body"_. Does `generate_invoice` return the PDF's binary data? Also, when you say _"the response has the PDF file"_ you already seem to serve it to the user. Can you clarify what's missing?

Comment: @Stefan What I do in the generate_invoice method is send a POST request to https://invoice-generator.com with the invoice parameters and finally return the response body (I think it is PDF's binary data as long as it can be written into a file locally with the 'wb' flag). It is served to the user from the server perspective but what I cannot figure out is how to render that PDF on the web browser after the user submitted the #new form.

Comment: Maybe the browser is lacking a PDF plugin. When you change the `disposition` value from `"inline"` to `"attachment"`, do you get a file download with a valid PDF file?